# In laravel job using database as queue connection. But queue:work command not triggering queues?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel job given queue connection as `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`. when using `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync` php artisan queue:work is running but when using `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` queue is not triggering. php artisan queue:listen also not triggering the job.

Comment: Make sure to clear the cache. use `php artisan config:cache` and the `php artisan queue:work`

Comment: Do you see any errors in the log file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is no error in log file.

Comment: Run `php artisan queue:restart`. Tell me if this works.

Comment: I have cleared cache also. Same error coming.

Comment: "Broadcasting queue restart signal." result get when php artisan queue:restart

Comment: That's true BUT is your queue working now?

Comment: No queue work its not triggering.

Comment: Are you sure you did `php artisan queue:table` and then `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: Yes. jobs are listed in jobs table also but after I run php artisan queue:work attempts remaining 0

Comment: Could you maybe show us a screenshot (preferably a gif) of what is happening and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please check the screen shots. https://imgur.com/ilQpVHz. https://imgur.com/8KVo8Pa. 
in env file I have used database as queue_connection

Answer (score 1):

You need to run

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

in one tab and another tab that is running

```
php artisan queue:work
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run

```
php artisan queue:work --queue orders
```